# Oracle error copying/uploading data TNS:bad packet

Tags: plsql, sql-loader, oracle12c

I'm receiving the following errors when trying to copy data across 2 databases:

ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE
ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet

The copy statement I'm using is

```
COPY FROM &&1 TO &&2 -
INSERT -
STG_CPS_TACCT_PROFIT -
USING -
SELECT MONTH_KEY, -
    ACCOUNT_KEY, -
    SCENARIO_KEY, -
    ... MORE COLUMNS ...
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS PROC_DT -
FROM CPS.TACCOUNT_PROFIT -
WHERE MONTH_KEY IN(&&3) -
AND SCENARIO_KEY IN(2, 3);
```

Same thing happens when processing a large file using SQL*Loader. Sometimes it manages to complete the load but other times it throws the error.

This only happens with big files/tables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: what version of the jdbc driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I posted this question. This ended up being a tuning issue with the database that the DBA group had to perform after migrating us from 11g to 12c. Once they got to it I stopped receiving this error. I don't have the details of what they did to fix it.

Comment: If you cannot fully answer this question, please do not post an answer.